# Enhanced Segmentation - Final send volume after exclusion

Tags: dataextensions, filters

I'm busy building filtered data extensions using the new enhanced segmentation features, so that we can drag and drop segments in to our sends.

So as an example I have created 2 filtered DEs, one with UK customers, and another with Irish customers.

I have then created another 2, one with any booked customers and another with non-booked customers.

Doing a fake send using these segments, I have added the UK customer DE as the target audience (101k records), and then added the Non-booked DE as an exclusion (98k). So this should send the email to our Booked UK customers.

But no where in the Send process can I see what the actual send volume will be based on this logic. Is it even possible to see this?

I used to write individual SQL queries to create bespoke data extensions based on the selection criteria and that would instantly tell us the final send volume, but my colleagues aren't SQL savvy, so using a drag-and-drop selection and exclusion method would work for them while I am away.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, during the sending process you are unable to see the send count when using exclusion/suppression lists until after sending.

Using the example you gave above, you can use ONE Master DE and filter off that. Flags can be used to indicate booked and not booked along with customer country.

Your filter would then look something like:

Country is equal to "UK"  AND 
BOOKED is not empty

This will give you the freedom to easily edit and refresh the filtered data extension prior to sending.